# How do I open a file in visidata with a specific separator?

Tags: csv, visidata

I have a csv file that uses "|" as separators. How can I open it in visidata so it recognized the "|" as the column separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it in the documentation, down at the bottom: https://www.visidata.org/docs/man/

```
visidata --csv-delimiter "|" filename.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the following:

vd -d '|' filename to open a pipe-separated text file.